# Is there anyway to get Model name based on table name

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

Is there any way to get **Model** name based on **table** name in Laravel?

For example, I have a **User** model:

```
class User extends Model {
    // This class is related to `users` table in Database.
}
```

Suppose that this **Model (User)** is related to **users** table in database. I want a function like this:

```
getModelName('users'); // This should return 'User'
```

Is there something like this?

Comment: `strtolower(__CLASS__);`

Comment: Just out of interest, what would be a use case for this?

Answer (score 6):

The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` has a function for returning the table name for the given model. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1951

You could reverse engineer this function to something like

```
function getModelName($table)
{
    return Str::studly(Str::singular($table));
}
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking about this. But still there is a problem, what about custom table names? suppose in my **User** model I have explicitly defined the related table: `protected $table = 'my_users'`. So in this case it will return **MyUser**, not **User**.

Comment: Model class no longer implements getModelName function, but the function `Str::studly(Str::singular($table));` is still working in Laravel 5.2

Comment: I am considering simply using an array to map table names to Models. It is plausible to have more than one Model for a given table (although possibly not recommended) so automating it is potentially risky.